# Social Security and Medicare taxes not withheld

Tags: united-states, irs, payroll-taxes, medicare, ssn

I have been working with same employer in the US since the start of H-1B in 2016.  I just noticed that my W2 shows no SS and Medicare paid by employer. Since I applied for a change of status from F1 to H1, and they forgot to change in the payroll, I have filed my taxes every year and did not get anything from IRS.

Should I ask my employer to look into this or leave it to the IRS and the employer? I am concerned that if I go and tell them, it might backfire and they may look down upon me.  Do I owe anything to the IRS?

Comment: The W2 never shows Social Security and Medicare Tax paid **by the employer**, only the Social Security and Medicare Tax _paid by the employee_ as a deduction from wages and _sent by the employer_ paying the wages to the Social Security administration.  The _employer_ is **also** taxed on the wages paid to the employee and must send in that amount to the Social Security Administration, but this number is _not_ shown on the employees's W2 form at all.  Note: in general, the employer's share and employee's share is the same amount, but for high earners, the employer pays the full tax... continued

Comment: ---- even if the employee is not subject to Social Security tax any more because the employee has already earned more than the maximum wages (about $110K) that is subject to Social Security for that year and so has zero _withholding_ for Social Security taxes.  Medicare taxes have no such maximum wage limit: both the employee and employer pay equal amounts regardless of the wages paid.

Comment: @DilipSarwate, you should 'convert' your comment into an answer because it an answer, and probably the correct one. Comments are for clarifying things the OP asked in their question.

Comment: @ender.qa The question is what to do with regard to the no withholding for SS and Medicare taxes (contact the employer and remind them that the OP is no longer exempt from SS and Medicare taxes and has not been so for n early three years, or keep mouth shut) and to that I have no answer or advice to give. So, I will keep my comments above as comments,  and not convert them to an answer.